# Could not deduce template argument - generic function

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class Iter, class T> T sum(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return std::accumulate(first, last, 0.0);
}

// Not compiled...
const double b = sum(v.begin(), v.end());

// Compiled
const double b = sum<std::vector<double>::const_iterator, double>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I want to write a generic template function that calculate the sum of a container. I want to achieve that without specifying the template argument. In my attempt, I had to define the two ugly parameters. How can I write a clean code? The function would have been pointless if the compiler can't do the job.

Using **Visual Studio 2013**

Comment: Which version of C++ is this?

Comment: The return type `T` cannot be deduced. do you want `double` or `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type`

Comment: I don't care. I just want to write a function that gives me a sum of the vector, but without me specifying the template arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type `T` can't be deduced from the iterator type.

In C++14, you could deduce it from the return value

```
template <class Iter> auto sum(Iter first, Iter last)
```

In C++11, you could get it from the iterator type

```
template <class Iter> auto sum(Iter first, Iter last) -> decltype(*first)
```

or from traits

```
template <class Iter> 
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type 
sum(Iter first, Iter last)
```

Historically, it would be awkward. You could make it the first parameter so the second can be deduced

```
template <class T, class Iter> T sum(Iter first, Iter last)

const double b = sum<double>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

or add an extra function parameter to specify the initial value; but then your function would be identical to `std::accumulate` itself.

You should use `T()` rather than `0.0` as the initial value, otherwise the calculation will be done using `double` whether or not that's suitable for the container type.

Answer (score 3):

The return type T cannot be deduced.

Following may help:

```
template <class Iter>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type sum(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return std::accumulate(first, last, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type{});
}
```